# Dynamic range for Rank Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

[Data sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xcqU.png)
Hi,

For given data, rank of "val" is given in Rn column, since there are duplicates entries I want the a function for rank to consider va2 value where val is repetitive. "Output is in Rn2 column which i want from formula". If val is unique it should give its rank from same column entries and when val is repetitive it should give rank based on va2 values.

Comment: I think you need to add a small dataset together with expected result to clarify your query.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the use of multiple sorting criteria. Specifically, in Excel 2010 and newer versions, you have an option under "Sorting and filtering" called "Custom sort". Here, you can arrange multiple levels of sorting criteria, *e.g.* sort descending by "Value 1", then sort descending by "Value 2". This will sort the table in the desired way. (Then, you can just start a new column, starting with 1,2 and drag down the auto-filler: these will be your rank numbers.)